# Encryption using AES_* functions and EVP_* functions

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, aes, evp-cipher

I have some data that was encrypted using the openssl (`AES_*`) functions. I want update this code to use the newer (`EVP_*`) functions. But should be able to decrypt data that was encrypted using the old code.

I've pasted below both the old and the new code. The encrypted/decrypted contents are different. i.e. I can't use them interchangeably. This means I can't upgrade the code without having to decrypt using the old code and then re-encrypt.

Are there any values for the parameters to `EVP_BytesToKey` so that `aes_key` derived is the same in both cases. Or is there any other way to accomplish the same using the (`EVP_*`) functions? I've tried several different values for `digest`, `rounds` and tried making `iv NULL`, but didn't really work i.e. it doesn't provide the same output as the old method.

The code using the `AES_*` functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <print_util.h>

static const unsigned char user_key[] = {
   0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03,
   0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13,
   0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23,
   0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33
};

int main()
{
    unsigned char p_text[]="plain text";
    unsigned char c_text[16];
    unsigned char d_text[16];

    AES_KEY aes_key;

    AES_set_encrypt_key(user_key, 128, &aes_key);
    AES_encrypt(p_text, c_text, &aes_key);

    printf("plain text = %s\n", p_text);
    printbuf((char*)c_text, 16, "cipher text = ");

    AES_set_decrypt_key(user_key, 128, &aes_key);
    AES_decrypt(c_text, d_text, &aes_key);
    printf("plain text (decrypted) = %s \n", d_text);

    return 0;
}
```

The code using the `EVP_*` functions. (Encryption code is below and the decryption code is similar).

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <print_util.h>

static const unsigned char user_key[16] = {
   0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03,
   0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13,
   0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23,
   0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33
};

int main()
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);

    const EVP_CIPHER *cipher = EVP_aes_128_ecb(); // key size 128, mode ecb
    const EVP_MD *digest = EVP_md5();
    int rounds = 10;
    unsigned char aes_key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
    unsigned char aes_iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];

    EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, digest, NULL, user_key, 16, rounds, aes_key, aes_iv);

    EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, cipher, aes_key, aes_iv);

    unsigned char p_text[]="plain text"; int p_len = sizeof(p_text);
    unsigned char c_text[16]; int c_len = 16;
    int t_len;

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, c_text, &c_len, p_text, p_len);
    EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, (c_text + c_len), &t_len);

    c_len += t_len;

    printf("==> p_text: %s\n", p_text);
    printbuf((char*)c_text, c_len, "==> c_text:");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You first example uses a raw key, while your second uses a key derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey`). ECB mode does not use an initialization vector. AES encryption always operates on 16 byte blocks (AES blocksize), so you are encrypting junk after the string `"plain text"` because the string is only 10 bytes. The `EVP_Encypt` is adding PKCS padding when `Final` is called.

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. The `EVP_*` functions use hardware, like AES-NI, if available. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: [OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both `EVP_BytesToKey` and commands like `openssl enc`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any key derivation in your `AES_*` code, so you should not use any key derivation such as `EVP_BytesToKey` in your new `EVP_` code if you want to stay fully compatible.

And no, there is no way to make `EVP_BytesToKey` output the same key as above, because a cryptographic hash is used to generate the output.

Comment: I've tried avoiding `EVP_BytesToKey` and use the `user_key` directly with a NULL `iv`, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: I would suggest to introduce backwards compatibility code, and transition people to use the new function